# react textarea value console warning

Tags: javascript, reactjs

My code is work fine but node is warning with this code:

```
<div id="info">
        <p> User:<b> {show.firstName} {show.lastName} </b></p>
        <textarea value={show.description}> </textarea>
        <p> Adress:<b> {show.address.streetAddress} </b></p>
</div>
```

Warning:

```
proxyConsole.js:56 Warning: Failed form propType: 
You provided a `value` prop to a form field without an `onChange` handler. 
This will render a read-only field. If the field should be mutable use `defaultValue`. 
Otherwise, set either `onChange` or `readOnly`. Check the render method of `Details`
```

if i change
`<textarea value={show.description}> </textarea>`

to

`<textarea defaultValue={show.description}> </textarea>`

or

`<textarea> {show.description}</textarea>`

i got error

`If you supply`defaultValue`on a <textarea>, do not pass children`

It's ok ? Or may be i'm doing something wrong. I don't need handler to textarea

Comment: This answer is about 6 years late, but I'm pretty sure the actual problem is the single space inside the tag. This is creating a TextNode with a single space in it, which React is passing as a child of the textarea.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you don't need to handle changes of `value` then you can ignore it, it's just a warning not an error.
With that being said, why would you use a text area for this purpose? use a `<label/>` or any other element that responsible for read only texts. keep in mind that from accessibility aspect your approach is not ideal  as screen readers can get confused.

**EDIT**
As a followup to your comment:

> But, why error with when use defaultValue
>
> If you supply defaultValue on a `<textarea>`, do not pass children

You can pass `defaultValue` but you can't supply children (like in a normal html situation).
Taken from the [DOCS](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/forms.html#the-textarea-tag):

> In HTML, a `<textarea>` element defines its text by its children
>   In React, a `<textarea>` uses a value attribute instead.